# ldap_search() doesnt return managedBy attribute

Tags: php, ldap

I have the follwing code.

```
$groupName = "Access to QC source file and symbol information"; 
$filter = "(cn=". $groupName . ")";  
$result = ldap_search($this->con, "OU=Distribution Groups,OU=Groups,DC=rim,DC=net", $filter, array('managedBy','msExchCoManagedByLink'));  
$entry = ldap_get_entries($this->con, $result);   
echo $entry[0]['managedby'][0];
```

$groupName exitsts in the MS outlook directory but it doesn't shows up. It simply returns 0. Please help.

Comment: What returns 0? The `echo` line? What if you do `var_dump($entry);`?

Comment: thanks mike for the ans. i solved the issue. i had to remove OU=Distribution Groups.